# Filtering table via Query builder - null value not selecting all

Tags: google-app-maker

When my drop-down "filter" has no value selected, my table displays zero records. I need it to select all values.

The table is tied to Datasource1 containing fields:Name, Status, Team1, and Team2. I have a second Datasource called Teams that contains team names. I setup query builder for Datasource1 to change based on a radio button(status) and a dropdown(teamFilter).

Datasource1 - Query Builder:

```
status= :status and (team1 = :teamFilter or team2 = :teamFilter)
```

Selecting a value in the drop-down properly filters the table. The issue is when no value is selected, or if I select the null option.

Comment: Please reference the documentation here https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/datasources#constructing_a_query, which addresses what is called the 'leaf' (?) operator. To consider a null value you would need =?.

Comment: Got it! Thank you.